# Enabling keyboard feature on Arduino with CH340G

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, keyboard, atmega16u2

I've seen [here](http://hackaday.com/2012/06/29/turning-an-arduino-into-a-usb-keyboard/) that it is possible to enable keyboard feature on Arduino Uno so it can emulate a keyboard (send keystrokes to computer) like the Leonardo. They do it by updating ATmega16U2 firmware. But I bought a cheap arduino clone that uses CH340G instead of this chip. Is there any way to do the same with this chip? Can this even work on standard arduino uno?

Comment: Maybe you can find/write a c/c++ program for the PC that reads a COM port and sends it as keystrokes. The hardware is pretty much fixed in your project. Unless you use an Arduino with 32uX aa a serial/USB interface chip.

Answer (score 2):

No. That chip can only act as a USB-UART bridge. You could use V-USB to turn the ATmega328P into a low-speed USB device, but the Arduino IDE has no support for that.